# Error: UID SEARCH Failure due to backend error. | IMAP UID, Node.JS, imap.yandex.ru, imap.search

Tags: node.js, imap

The problem i faced using [node-imap API][1] relates with this ERROR.

```
Error: UID SEARCH Failure due to backend error.
```

I need search some mails of my box with imap.search, and if i use criteria like this -  [ ['HEADER', 'SUBJECT', 'node-imap'] ] - search by 'SUBJECT' i get error i wrote above.

BUT if i use criteria of search without 'HEADER', for example [ 'UNSEEN', ['SINCE', 'April 20, 2010'] ] - my programm works good.

i wrote to helpdesk of yandex and they told me that problem appears because of i did not set all personal data in my account. However, i think this is not from that, because i tested on another account yandex with all personal data and the same problem is.

Interesting that, when i use criteria with HEADER SUBJECT i can launch code 10 times and 5 times it will be works good, the rest not. some strange... But if i use criteria of imap.search without HEADER it works good alwasys.

this my code

```
const imap = new Imap({
    user: 'myemail@yandex.ru',
    password: 'mypassword',
    host: 'imap.yandex.ru',
    port: 993,
    tls: true
});

imap.once('ready', () => {
    imap.openBox('INBOX', true, (err, box) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        imap.search([
            ['ON', 'Dec 17, 2019'] //it works good!, BUT this criteria not --> [ ['HEADER', 'SUBJECT', 'node-imap'] ]
        ], (err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            const f = imap.fetch(res, { struct: true });

            f.on('message', (msg, seqno) => {
                console.log('Message №%d', seqno);

                msg.once('attributes', (attrs) => {
                    const attachments = inspect(attrs.struct, true, 8);
                });
            });

            imap.end();
        });
    });
});

imap.once('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

imap.once('end', () => {
    console.log('Connection ended');
});

imap.connect();
```

Comment: I don't actually see a search command in your code.  Did you remove it?

Comment: i apologize, i meant open first email in current case.

Comment: The error probably means that there's a server internally at the server. Yandex' IMAP server cannot reach the storage subsystem where the mail is actually stored, or something like that. It's not actually an IMAP problem. You may or may not be able to work around it, but if I were you I'd just report it to Yandex. I hope you're a paying customer? Good luck either way.

Comment: i sent request to Yandex also, but didn't get resp yet. You think, that problem is on Yandex side?

Comment: I have the same problem. The most of requests are failed with the same error. I also search messages by subject.